# How to make my program JLabel selection random

Tags: java, random, jlabel

Here is my code.new with this .thanks in advance
im not sure how to use the random generator...i want to randomize my correct answer...i want to make sure that the next selection will not be the same jlabel ive selected..thank you very much if you could help me...new in programming here...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NumberFinder extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout();
Font aFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 100);
Font bFont = new Font("Century", Font.BOLD, 20);

JLabel a = new JLabel("1");
JLabel b = new JLabel("2");
JLabel c = new JLabel("3");
JLabel d = new JLabel("4");
JLabel ed = new JLabel("5");
JLabel f = new JLabel("6");
JLabel g = new JLabel("7");
JLabel h = new JLabel("8");
JLabel i = new JLabel("9");
JLabel j = new JLabel("");
int ran = 0;
int count = 0;


public NumberFinder()
{
    super("Number Finder");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(f1);
    a.setFont(aFont);
    b.setFont(aFont);
    c.setFont(aFont);
    d.setFont(aFont);
    ed.setFont(aFont);
    f.setFont(aFont);
    g.setFont(aFont);
    h.setFont(aFont);
    i.setFont(aFont);
    j.setFont(bFont);
    add(a);
    add(b);
    add(c);
    add(d);
    add(ed);
    add(f);
    add(g);
    add(h);
    add(i);
    add(j);
    a.addMouseListener(this);
    b.addMouseListener(this);
    c.addMouseListener(this);
    d.addMouseListener(this);
    ed.addMouseListener(this);
    f.addMouseListener(this);
    g.addMouseListener(this);
    h.addMouseListener(this);
    i.addMouseListener(this);

}



public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==a)
    {
    a.getText();
    j.setText("Try Again");
    a.setEnabled(false);
    count ++;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==b)
    {
    b.getText();
    j.setText("Correct!");
    b.setEnabled(true);
    count ++;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==c)
    {
        c.getText();
        j.setText("Try Again");
        c.setEnabled(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==d)
    {
        d.getText();
        j.setText("Try again");
        d.setEnabled(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==ed){
        ed.getText();
        j.setText("Try Again");
        ed.setEnabled(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==f){
        f.getText();
        j.setText("Try Again");
        f.setEnabled(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==g){
        g.getText();
        j.setText("Try Again");
        f.setEnabled(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==h){
        h.getText();
        j.setText("Try Again");
        h.setEnabled(false);
        count++;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==i){
        i.getText();
        j.setText("Try Again");
        i.setEnabled(false);
        count++;
    }}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){      
}



}
```

Comment: Add them to some kind of `List`, use `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle the list, add them to your panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your labels to some kind of `List`...

```
JLabel[] arrayOfLables = {
    new JLabel("1"), 
    new JLabel("2"), 
    new JLabel("3"), 
    new JLabel("4"), 
    new JLabel("5"), 
    new JLabel("6"), 
    new JLabel("7"), 
    new JLabel("8"), 
    new JLabel("9"), 
    new JLabel("")};
List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfLables));
```

Use `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle the list...

```
Collections.shuffle(labels);
```

Add them to you container...

```
for (JLabel label : labels) {
    add(label);
}
```

Comment: could you help me sir to put it on my code...we never actually did use arraylist before..i dont know where to add them...my first time hearing the collections.shuffle ....thank you sir for helping ....

Comment: thank you for the help sir...im sorry...my bad...i think my english is that bad that it is a misunderstanding...not that i want to shuffle my selection...i just want to randomize my correct answer...sorry for my first question...if someone answered it correctly...next time that it will be answered...the answer will be different...the jlabel answer will be different..thanks in advance sir....